# Modular arithmetic $a=bq+r$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, proof-explanation

How do I show that if $r$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $b$ (e.g. $a = bq + r$) then $a\equiv r (\mod b)$?

I assume I'm supposed to use the division algorithm and/or the quotient remainder theorem.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of $a \equiv r\pmod{b}$?  That is, if you have (for example) 3 positive integers, $a,r,b$, then what is the **exact** specification for determining whether $a \equiv r\pmod{b}?$

Comment: Re my previous comment, your reference to the division algorithm &/or quotient remainder is all **cart before the horse**.  The question in the previous comment **must** be answered, **before** your query can be attacked.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack.

Comment: @haidangel Thank you for the suggestion! I'll make sure my formatting is correct from now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definition of congruence modulo $b$:

$a\equiv r\mod b$ iff $b\mid a-r$ (divisibility) iff there exists $q$ such that $bq = a-r$.

Now if $a=bq+r$, then $b\mid a-r$ and so $a\equiv r\mod b$.

Comment: I was hoping that the OP would be forced to take the trouble to dig out the definition that the OP had been taught.  Why not delete your answer?

Comment: @user2661923 it was a "challenge" question meaning I had not been taught this material. I only wished to explore the subject further. Thank you.

Comment: @swk23C8 No one had any way of knowing either the background of the problem, or your background.  Your query has already received two votes to close the query.  For a discussion of defects found in mathSE queries, see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: @user2661923 Sorry about that, I'll make sure to take the pointers in that answer into my posts. Thank you for the link.